# AngularJS ng-repeat directive loses data after update data parent $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, notifications

I have a notifications page generated by a ng-repeat looking like this: [image: notifications]

The list is generated like this:

```
<div id="notifications" class="page_content">
  <div class="notification center" notification-view notification="notification" providers="notifications.providers" ng-repeat="notification in notificationsObjects">
  </div>
```

After the user completed the notification (and the data is updated in the database) I update the notificationsObjects array by removing the completed notification. I do this with the following function:

```
$scope.removeNotificationFromNotificationList = function(notification){
  for(var i = 0; i<$scope.notificationsObjects.length; i++){
    if($scope.notificationsObjects[i].id == notification.id){
      var indexToRemove = $scope.notificationsObjects.indexOf($scope.notificationsObjects[i]);
      var updatedArray = $scope.notificationsObjects;
        updatedArray.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
      $scope.notificationsObjects = updatedArray;
    }
  }
}
```

But after updating the array, this happens although the data is still available:
[image: notifications2]
The 2 arrays (before and after updating) look exactly what I expect but for some reason the directive for a single notification doesn't have the notification object anymore. These are the 2 notificationsObjects arrays (before and after removing the completed notification):
[image: notifications data]

I thought by just recalculating the notifications and reset the new $scope.notificationsObjects would solve my problem, and it does, but it reloads my whole DOM and I don't want that. I just want the completed notification to disappear from the array (and so, remove it from the DOM). Does anyone have a clue what causes this problem, or does anyone have a better solution to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you create a sample PLUNKER or some demo ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now but didn't really find the cause. I noticed some variables in the single notification directive not being set on the $scope. Even though they were not depending on changes, I coupled them to the $scope and the problem was solved.